# How do I pronounce a B, D, or G before an E at the end of a word?

Tags: pronunciation

I've been wondering about this for some words such as "Tage"

Is it pronounced Tah-kuh or Tah-guh?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*b*, *d*, and *g* are pronounced like *p*, *t*, and *k*, if they occur *at the end* of a syllable. This effect is known as final-obstruent devoicing, or in German, Auslautverhärtung. Since *Tage* is split into syllables like *Ta-ge*, the *g* is not at the end of a syllable, so it is *not* pronounced as *k*.

Comment: As the "Auslautverhärtung" *not* happens when followed by a "e", that's actually a way how German schoolchildren learn to "hear" how a word is written correctly: Form the Plural ( or other related word). While "Hund" or "Hunt*"is hard to hear, "Hun*d*e" becomes clear.